# Should I ask the user to post score to leaderboard

Tags: game-center, leaderboard

Just asking for a clarification on posting scores to Game Center:

I've an authenticated player. Once he finishes a game, should I ask him if he wants to upload his score or just do that automatically since he's connected? Should I display an option for this in settings (enable auto upload of score)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends. Since you've not given me enough information, I'm just going to go on basic computing instincts.

If you want to be efficient in terms of backing storage then ask him. If not and you don't mind about backing storage, just save the scores.

You want to be more user-friendly? Then ask him.

Etc, Etc.

Comment: I don't have to worry about how much space I have in Apple's servers. I realised I shouldn't ask cause if he's enabled Game Center then he would probably wants to upload his score.